# Google Appengine: Datastore query specifies a filter, the fields in the result are opposite

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I'm running python appengine in the dev server. I get this surprising result when I look at this query in the debug console:

```
Invoice.query(Invoice.number == 3281, Invoice.paid == True).fetch()[0].paid
```

> > False

So the query is supposed to select items that match **Invoice.paid == True** but it in fact returns an item that has **Invoice.paid == False**. Any idea why this may be occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I forgot to do invoice.put() after changing the 'paid' field. So it seems somehow in python the field was set to False but in the Datastore it was still True. It is strange though, that the query apparently returns a result that contradicts the filter.